# Can a sentence adverb function as a focusing adverb?

Tags: adverbs

> He plays soccer, surprisingly, at home.

Does it mean different from “surprisingly, he plays soccer at home” or “he, surprisingly, plays soccer at home”? Precisely saying, does “surprisingly” focus on “at home” in the sentence?

Answer (score 1):

In this form, "surprisingly" will more often refer to the part that follows it, but it could refer to what comes before, depending on the context.

In your example, it's surprising that someone would play soccer at home, so it clearly applies to "at home".

But take this example:

> He painted scissors on his fence, surprisingly, in his back yard.

Here, the surprising part is that he painted scissors on his fence. "...in his back yard" simply refers to where the fence is.